# Does it can ...? reply "Yes, it can" or "Yes, it can do it." or "Yes, it can do"?

Tags: american-english

e.g:

Some One: As normal the packing list is showing one item per sheet.  Does it can show multi-item by one sheet?

Which one is normal?
"Yes, it can" or "Yes, it can do it." or "Yes, it can do"?

Comment: "Does it can ..." is ungrammatical. It should be "Can it ...".

Comment: "Can it show multiple items/more than one item on each sheet?" "Yes, it can."

Comment: Thanks, could you answer below, I'll mark answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Does it can* is ungrammatical. The correct question is *Can it?*

> Can it show multiple items [*or* more than one item] on each sheet? Answer: Yes, it can.

*Yes, it can do that* or *do so* would be correct, but rather formal.